# transmission daemon won't start

Tags: raspbian

I was following this guy's tutorial
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-transmission/comment-page-1/#comment-63304

I did everything right (triple checked)
but i got stuck at this line of code

```
sudo systemctl start transmission-daemon

Job for transmission-daemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status transmission-daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: What does a `journalctl -xe` command tell you? How does transmission-daemon fail?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by uninstalling and reinstalling the transmission-daemon.

First run,

```
sudo apt remove transmission-daemon
```

Then.

```
sudo apt install transmission-daemon
```